# Why does calling a state change multiple times not cause multiple re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, react-hooks

```
interface params{
  texts: string[];
  handlePropertyTerm: (value:string) => void;
}

let SortOptions = React.memo(({texts, handlePropertyTerm}:params) => (
    <>
      {texts.map((text) => (
        <button key={text} defaultValue={text} onClick={() => handlePropertyTerm(text)}>{text}</button>
      ))}
    </>
));
```

```
function App(){
    let [sortProperty, setPropertyTerm] = React.useState("");
    let sortPropertyTerm = React.useCallback((value) => {
        console.log("Callback value:", value);
        setPropertyTerm(value);
    }, []);
    console.log("App");


    return (
    <>
    <SortOptions texts={["hi", "bye"]} handlePropertyTerm={sortPropertyTerm}></SortOptions>
    </>
    );
}
```

The code i described above creates two buttons one called `hi` and another called `bye` each with a callback which causes the `sortProperty` to contain either "hi" or "bye" depending on the button clicked.
After App first loads and i click the `hi` button, it will log **Callback value = hi** and **App**. I believe this is because there was a state change in App causing a re-render.
When I click `hi` the second time the same statements are logged.
When I click `hi` the third time, only the **Callback value = hi** is logged.

Please can someone explain what is causing App to be re-rendered the second time I click `hi` but not the third time?

Comment: I removed my answer since this is a duplicate. Does this answer your question? [React hooks useState setValue still rerender one more time when value is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal) Just to point it out: it has **nothing to do** with your `React.memo` or `React.useCallback`. That's just how react handles state updates.

Comment: @ysfaran yes this is what I was looking for, i posted a new question making my issue even clearer and essentially you answered that question too. Thanks!