# Why is react component function executed even when the state variable value is not changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used `npx create-react-app` to create a react app. Following are the index.js and App.js code:

**Index.js** (did not use StrictMode)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

**App.js**

```
import {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  console.log('App component function executed');

  const [name, setName] = useState('name');
  const changeNameHandler = () => {
    setName('newname');
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {name}
      <button onClick={changeNameHandler}>Change Name</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I start the app I see 'App component function executed' in the console for the first time which is expected.
Then I click the 'Change Name' button and see another 'App component function executed' in the console, still expected.

At this point the state has been set to 'newname' so when I click the button again, new message should not be logged in the console, but it again consoles 'App component function executed'. Clicking the button further doesn't do anything.

I expected that 'App component function executed' would be logged only 2 time (first at initial mounting and when the button is clicked the first time). Or it would be logged every time I click the button. But I see it logging exactly 3 times.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: I guess because your `changeNameHandler`  sets a new name, even if it's the old name, it still sets `state` ... just a guess though

Comment: Then it should not stop at 3 logs.

Comment: Check this post which is similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/q/57652176/7785337

Comment: oh, I didn't realise it stops :p I dont' know react very well, do I :D

Comment: No problem! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks useState setValue still rerender one more time when value is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I am new to react, still can't clearly understand why this is happening.

Comment: @user123456789 read the answer, it seems react still renders, when you set state to same value, and then it bails out

Answer (score -2):

Every time the button is clicked, the state is set. Even tho it is being set to the same string, the state is still changing and thus causing that component to re-render. This is why you are seeing the console log every time the button is clicked.

useState doesn't have its own memoization built-in. As you are setting the state to the same string on the button click, look into memoization in react. This should solve this problem