# Why do components in react only renders twice when I change the state from the button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have been learning react recently, and I created a component in which I have created three buttons: "post", "user", and "comment". When I click one of the buttons, the name of the button shows below the buttons and also logs the button's name, which is console. I am confused as to why a button logs the name only twice in console if clicked consecutively, since from my understanding it should log only once. I tried removing <React.StrictMode> from the index.js file but still it only logs twice. Example: if the user button is clicked twice consecutively, it logs its name twice but not more if clicked again, it should log into the console only once. I think it is related to the useState hook. Please help me understand this react behaviour. Here is my code:

```
export default function Hello() {

const [resourceType, setResourceType] = useState('post')

console.log(resourceType)

return (
  <div>
      <button onClick={() => setResourceType('post')}>Post</button>
      <button onClick={() => setResourceType('user')}>User</button>
      <button onClick={() => setResourceType('comment')}>Comments</button>
      <h1>{resourceType}</h1>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This will probably give you the idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

Comment: I removed the strict mode but still i dont think it is related to strict mode.

Comment: I think here you can find answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal

Answer (score 4):

The value is logged twice on two consecutive clicks of the same button, and then not on subsequent consecutive clicks, because of the State hook's *bailout*. As @Armands alluded to in his comment, the answer is in the [React docs (API Hooks Reference)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal) which states:

> **Bailing out of a state update**
> If you update a State Hook to the same
> value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the
> children or firing effects.
>
> ***Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.***

So if your case, since the `console.log(...)` is in the component body, it's still being fired before React "bails out".

Answer (score 2):

**React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props**.  in your case clicking the button the **first time**, changes the state `setResourceType('post')` which causes a `re-render` and executes `console.log(resourceType)`. but clicking it the **second time** will not change the state it is the same `resourceType = 'post'` in this phase React may still need to re-render that specific component again and `console.log(resourceType)` will be executed. then it stops rerendering in spite of clicking the button .

**Note :** `onClick` is an  Event handler only re-run when you perform the same interaction again (clicking the button )

change your component like this if you want to log `resourceType` to the console every time you click the button :

```
 const [resourceType, setResourceType] = useState('post') 
  
return (
  <div>
      <button onClick={ ()=>{ setResourceType('post'); console.log( resourceType)} }>Post</button>
      <button onClick={() =>{ setResourceType('user'); console.log( resourceType)}}>User</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setResourceType('comment'); console.log( resourceType)}}>Comments</button>
      <h1>{resourceType}</h1>
  </div>
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason can be found in the react documentation React docs [(API Hooks Reference)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> Bailing out of a state update If you update a State Hook to the same
> value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the
> children or firing effects.
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).