# Changing the React component state with same value on button click trigger re-render for the first two button clicks. Why UI re-rendering twice?

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the 'Rerender UI' button then it prints in the console for the first two clicks. I think it should print in the console only for the first time when I click on the 'Rerender UI' button because on the button click the component state is changed so UI will re-render and the console log will be printed in the console. Why is it printing for the second click? StrictMode is off. See code:

```
export default function UseCallbackComp() {
  const [stateVar, setStateVar] = useState<any>()
  console.log("Parent Rerendered!")
  return (
    <>
      <div>UseCallbackComp content</div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setStateVar(1)
          }}
        >
          Rerender UI
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

When I put the console log line inside useEffect like below it prints only for the first time 'ReRender UI' button is clicked which is the expected behaviour.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent Rerendered!")
  })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks useState setValue still rerender one more time when value is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal)

Comment: @YellowD in the question that you have shared, the selected answer points to another question and there the selected answer says: "For a functional component using useState hook, the setter if called with the same state will not trigger a re-render. However for an occasional case if the setter is called **immediately** it does result in two renders instead of one"... 
But in my case, I am not calling the setter immediately. It doesn't matter after how much time I click on the button and set the state, it always causes the second re-render due to button click. Why?

Comment: @Gavit This comment provided from other answer might explain more about this: 
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810#issuecomment-462089702

Comment: Thanks @YellowD. From the above mentioned thread I got to know exactly how react useState works. Mentioning the same as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below two links I got to know whats the behaviour of react when useState is used:

1. [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal)
2. [gitHub discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810#issuecomment-462089702)

There are two different cases for which useState behaves differently for same value.

**Case 1**: When useState used with same value as the initial value.

**Result**: No rerendering at all.

```
export default function LifecycleEvents() {
  const [stateVar, setStateVar] = useState<any>(0)
  console.log("Parent Rerendered!")
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setStateVar(0) //same value as the initial value
        }}
      >
        Rerender UI
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Case 2**: When useState used with different value first and then with the same value.

**Result**: First both Parent and child will be re-rendered. But for the second time, only the render function of Parent component will get called, Nothing else.
See code:

```
export default function LifecycleEvents() {
  const [stateVar, setStateVar] = useState<any>(0)
  console.log("Parent Rerendered!")
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setStateVar(1) //different value then initial value.
        }}
      >
        Rerender UI
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Conclusion**: Nothing to worry unless you have an expensive render method of the component. In that case use *memo*.