# Why React needs another render to bail out state updates?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following `Component`

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [state, setState] = useState(null)

    const onClick = () => setState('foo')        

    console.log(state)

    return <button onClick={onClick}> Change </button>   
}
```

[image: Edit sad-thompson-s3l3i]

- Before pressing the button `console` just prints `null`
- First time button is pressed `console` prints `foo`
- Second time button is pressend `console` print `foo`
- Third time and forward `console` doesn't print anything

I understand that `console` doesn't print anything cause I'm calling `setState` passing  the same value as the current state and React is [bailing out the state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html). My question is about the following assertion

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

Why is this extra render necessary? I mean, Isn't `Object.is` returning `false` since the second click?

Comment: This has been asked and answered here, but not *explained*, sadly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373878/react-re-rendering-on-setting-state-hooks-vs-this-setstate

Comment: Yes. I didn't found the answer yet hahah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a satisfatory answer from a deleted answer in this same question. [d.c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14915496/d-c) pointed that Dan Abrahmov gave an answer in this [old github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14994#issuecomment-468779750).
Quoting Dan:

> I think at the time we decided that we don't actually know if it's safe to bail out in all cases until we try render again. The "bailout" here means that it doesn't go ahead to render children. But re-running the same function might be necessary (for example, if a reducer is inline and we don't know if we bail out until we re-run the reducer on next render). So for consistency we always re-run it on updates during the render phase.

Answer (score 5):

Internally useState is a [useReducer](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L336), with a [basicReducer](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L322), 
The hooks uses a queue of changes in order to update the [states](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L346).

AFAIK after looking the code it is a condition where the memoizedState is not fully processed in the queue, because is no using the fine control of the hook useMemo

Comment: The comment of the src code  "TODO: Not sure if this is the desired semantics, but it's what we do for gDSFP. I can't remember why." rofl

Comment: interesting angle view