# ReactJS double render for a Boolean state with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just playing around with ReactJS and trying to figure out some strange behavior with the useState hook.

A component should not re-rendered if the state is set with the same primitive value (Boolean) as it was before

```
const useScroll = ({positionToCross = 10}) => {

    const window = useWindow();
    const [isPositionCrossed, setIsPositionCrossed] = useState(window.scrollY > positionToCross);

    useEffect(() => {

        const onScroll = function (e) {

            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                const lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
                setIsPositionCrossed(lastKnownScrollPosition > positionToCross);
            });

        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
        }

    }, []);


    console.log(`useScroll - render window.scrollY = ${window.scrollY.toFixed(0)} isPositionCrossed = `, isPositionCrossed)
    return {isPositionCrossed}
}
```

here is the console output - you can see the component and the hook are both rendered two times with "true" (after scrolled over 100px)

```
"useScroll - render window.scrollY = 101 isPositionCrossed = ", true
"useScroll - render window.scrollY = 103 isPositionCrossed = ", true
```

Comment: Are you running in a development environment with `StrictMode` on, in a React version above 16.8.0? Many functions are intentionally called twice in that case to assist in debugging side effects, but in a production build they are only called once, as you would expect.

Comment: I just tried to remove the `StrictMode` in my app and it behave the same. React version is `17.0.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why React needs another render to bail out state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208727/why-react-needs-another-render-to-bail-out-state-updates)

Comment: In general, "why does React call my component function more than once" is an unnecessary question. React is absolutely at its leisure to call your function as many times as it pleases; that's why the function is supposed to be pure (aside from hooks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try [simple code](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-water-lg46c?file=/src/App.js) that on click handler setState and if you click two times and in each update state with same value the component again re-render.
As [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) says:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

I hope the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208727/why-react-needs-another-render-to-bail-out-state-updates) and this [github discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14994)  help you to understand why this happens

and there are another related topics like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373878/what-are-the-differences-when-re-rendering-after-state-was-set-with-hooks-compar)

Comment: did you see this post about differences between class component and function compoennt and useState , setState? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373878/what-are-the-differences-when-re-rendering-after-state-was-set-with-hooks-compar

Comment: its not related to scroll or anything its react that says: Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tre

Comment: see this post i hope help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208727/why-react-needs-another-render-to-bail-out-state-updates

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14994#issuecomment-468779750

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240621/discussion-between-hdm91-and-hartatovich).