# Set state with same value using hooks will cause a rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using hooks, If I call `setState` with the same value as the `state`, will it rerender the component?

If yes, **how can I avoid that?**

e.g.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(foo)

...
// any where in the code
setState(foo)
```

Considering that `foo` can be any thing, such as `{}`, `true`, `props.bar` or a variable from out side of the component (constant).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It won't re-render the component if you call `setState` with the same value.

Try this out:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const foo = { foo: 'bar' };

export default ({ name }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(foo);
  console.log("rendered!");
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(foo);
    console.log("state reset!");
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("handleClick!");
    setState(foo);
    // setState({ ...foo, bar : 'baz' });
  }

  return (<div>
  <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
  <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
  </div>);
};
```

You'll notice that even when the button is clicked since the value has not changed. it's not re-rendering the Component. If you change the argument that you call `setState` with, it will re-render the component.

---

> Here's a [**Code Sample**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-test-for-re-render?file=Hello.js) for your ref.

Try commenting the first `setState` and un-commenting the second one inside the `handleClick` method to see the difference.

Comment: I think, it is not re rendered, it is re evaluated by the virtual dom, and if there is a change only  then re render occurs in the real dom?

Comment: Just wanted to add another reference to confirm this. The React Hooks docs mention:
`If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.`
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Adding a note here for the above example. If you use a literal object like this `setState({ foo: 'bar' })`, it will always be re-rendered even if the object looks the same.

That's because each time a literal object is created, it's considered different from the old object. 

Just like when you compare two literal object `{a: 1} === {a: 1}` it returns `false`

Answer (score 17):

just to summarize

if your state is a **primitive value**(number, string, boolean, ...), then setting the same value using setState hook **won't trigger a rerender**. If your state is an Object or Array then it will behave differently.

https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/
https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/

Comment: I don't think we should differentiate. If it's the same (same reference) object or array, either because it's declared outside of the render function or through `useMemo`, it won't trigger a rerender. So we can simply say "if `Object.is(prevValue, newValue)` returns `true`, it won't rerender".

Comment: true, in addition to that, as far as I know, react uses Object.is() method for comparing values in dependency arrays(useMemo, useEffect, etc).
I'm assuming that it also uses that method for comparing values which you pass as a parameter to setState function and your current state.

Answer (score 3):

It's a js syntax related question, Just like `===` operation.

```
let times = 0
const init = {name: 'Bob'}
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(init)
  function modify() {
    setState({name: 'Bob'})
  }
  function modify2() {
    setState(init)
  }
  times ++
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{ times }</p>
      <button onClick={modify}>Same Value Will Rerender</button>
      <button onClick={modify2}>Same Reference Never Rerender</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-haze-6ttm0)

You can rewrite a wrapper method:

```
let times = 0
const init = {name: 'Bob'}
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(init)
  function modify3() {
    setState2({ name: 'Bob' })
  }
  function setState2(value) {
    if (value.name === state.name) {
      return
    }
    setState(value)
  }
  times ++
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{ times }</p>
      <button onClick={modify3}>Same Value Will Not Rerender Yet</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but I found an odd case in which setting the state with the same value triggers re-render twice and then usually behaves. setting the state to 2 will trigger re-render twice.

any explanation?

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(1);
  console.log("App rendered");
  console.log({ state });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState(1);
        }}
      >
        update state with same value
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState(2);
        }}
      >
        update state with different value
      </button>
      <div>state：{state}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I thought it's because of Strict Mode's double-render, but looks like it's not the case: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-lake-h34byu?file=/src/App.js:127-128. 
It's strange yeah, when you click the other button 2 times it allows 2 renders, then if you click the first again - it will allow 2 renders again. 
I'm not sure why honestly looks like react's internal implementation specifics?

Answer (score 1):

If the setState function or even useReducer Hook returns the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects because it uses the **Object.is comparison algorithm**.

Answer (score 0):

may you read this articl , it has good info connect with the subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374111/17262218

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33519516)