# React Native: infinite re-render when setting variable to same value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, memoization, react-functional-component, react-memo

I'm using a React Native functional component as follows:

```
export const Component1 = () => {
  const [var1, setVar1] = useState(false);
  setVar1(false);
  return (
    <View...>
  )
}
```

This goes into an infinite loop, but when I remove the `setVar1(false)`, it doesn't. I assumed the component wouldn't re-render if I kept re-setting `var1` to the same `false` value. How do I prevent this re-render?

Comment: Don't set state directly in the component's body

Comment: Where should I set it?

Comment: When some event occurs for example or inside `useEffect` hook.

Comment: It would work if you would change the state after timeout https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-surf-owqokm?file=/src/App.js You are getting an infinite loop, because react didn't finish the original render and you are already setting the state which causes the rerender.

Comment: If that is true, it would account for the first rerender. But what about the second?

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski, you said that the state causes the re-render, but why is it re-rendering if you set the same value? It isn't suppose to re-render. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489959/set-state-with-same-value-using-hooks-will-cause-a-rerender .                    
 I've just tried something that update the state inside ```useEffect``` with that state as dependency, But  I because I updated it to the same state - it didn't cause any infinte loop. So why when you update directly in the component body that what's happens?

Comment: [too many rerenders example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dream-bqs7rh?file=/src/App.js) - I guess that `useState` postpone some work for later in the first render and it doesn't see that the same value has been provided. Just a guess, I'm not an expert

Comment: I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034012/why-doesnt-setstate-usestate-correctly-recognize-same-value-in-the-initial-re) if anyone will be interested

Answer (score 0):

do not update the state directly it will cause  Too many re-renders. and React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

what you did is that the `setVar1` function gets invoked when the component renders, then updates the state, which causes a re-render and does that infinitely.  to prevent this behaviour it should be updated using a condition or an event handler or in useEffect