# Trace which change of props or state trigger `componentDidUpdate`

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, react-lifecycle

I'm making a webpage with react-monaco-editor. I realized that after loading the first page, `componentDidUpdate` is triggered many times, which does not look normal.

I tried to add logs in `componentDidUpdate`:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate")
    for (var key in prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (prevProps[key] !== this.props[key]) {
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "prevProps[key]", prevProps[key]);
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "this.props[key]", this.props[key])
          }
      }
    }

    for (var key in prevState) {
      if (prevState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (prevState[key] !== this.state[key]) {
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "prevState[key]", prevState[key]);
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "this.state[key]", this.state[key])
          }
      }
    }
   ... ...
   ... ...
```

Then, it prints the following logs. However, I don't see the difference of props or state.

[image]

Then, I tried to add logs as follows:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate")
    for (var key in prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (prevProps[key] !== this.props[key]) {
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "prevProps[key]", prevProps[key]);
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "this.props[key]", this.props[key])
          }
      }
    }

    for (var key in prevState) {
      if (prevState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (prevState[key] !== undefined && this.state[key] !== undefined && prevState[key].toString !== this.state[key].toString) {
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "prevState[key]", prevState[key]);
            console.log("debugha, componentDidUpdate, key", key, "this.state[key]", this.state[key])
          }
      }
    }
```

Then, it prints the following logs. It shows that the `toString` of props or state does not change.

[image]

So could anyone tell me how I could trace which props or state trigger `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: did you try and get the same result within a functional component as well?

Comment: I did not convert these (complex) class components to functional components.

Answer (score 2):

```
prevState[key].toString !== this.state[key].toString
```

This tells that you're comparing with function signature and thus you cannot detect the change. You need to call it to get the changes:

```
prevState[key].toString() !== this.state[key].toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tools and techniques for troubleshooting, I would suggest react dev tools extension - it produces something similar to what your  console log statements are looking to do. There is a [using react dev tools for rerender tutorial](https://jsramblings.com/how-to-check-if-your-component-rerendered-and-why) that provides an overview.

If you are looking for guesses on why the rerenders happen in my experience it is [often mutability that creates spurious rerenders](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data). The clearest explanation is in this comment on performance, basically [that {a:1} === {a:1} returns false because they are two different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489959/set-state-with-same-value-using-hooks-will-cause-a-rerender#comment126395185_59490103) in contrast to 1===1 which returns true.