# abort state set with React useState hook function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With the old class-based `this.setState()` method, we could return `null` from a function passed to `setState` to tell React not to do anything with that specific `setState` call:

```
this.setState(({ value }) => {
  if (value === 0) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { value: value - 1 };
  }
});
```

I'm trying to understand what's the correct way to do this with React Hooks, is the below correct?

```
const [x, setValue] = useState(0);
setValue(value => {
  if (value === 0) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return value - 1;
  }
});
```

I'm trying not to trigger a re-render if I pass the original value.

Comment: @NikitaMadeev see https://blog.logrocket.com/returning-null-from-setstate-in-react-16-5fdb1c35d457/

Comment: Oh, did not know about this possibility. Then your solution looks to work because [If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373878/what-are-the-differences-when-re-rendering-after-state-was-set-with-hooks-compar)

Answer (score 1):

React shouldn't rerender. From react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):
"If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
setValue(value => {
  if (value === 0) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return value - 1;
  }
});
}, [x])
```

Effect will only run if `x` changes.

Comment: I'm working with objects so it's not so straight forward unfortunately.

Comment: How so ? `x` is a number in your example.

Comment: That's a simplified example, I'm looking for a general purpose solution though