# Don't update children use react useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have two children Components, when I `onChange` in first children, then the second children re render, I don't want to the second children re render. Online code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-glitter-r5gnh3?file=/src/App.js:1287-1297

```js
const EditSceneModalStore = React.createContext(undefined);

const Parent = () => {
  const [saveValue, setSaveValue] = React.useState({});
  const initValue = {
    name: "zhang",
    age: 3
  };

  const onSave = () => {
    console.log("===saveValue==", saveValue);
  };

  const onChangeValue = (key, value) => {
    const newValue = {
      ...saveValue,
      [key]: value
    };
    setSaveValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <EditSceneModalStore.Provider
      value={{
        initValue,
        onChangeValue
      }}
    >
        <ChildInput1 />
        <ChildInput2 />
        <Button onClick={onSave} type="primary">
          save
        </Button>
    </EditSceneModalStore.Provider>
  );
};

const ChildInput1 = () => {
  const { onChangeValue, initValue } = React.useContext(EditSceneModalStore);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue.name);
  return (
    <Input
      value={value}
      onChange={(v) => {
        setValue(v.target.value);
        onChangeValue("name", v.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const ChildInput2 = () => {
  const { initValue, onChangeValue } = React.useContext(EditSceneModalStore);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue.InputNumber);
  console.log("====ChildInput2===");
  return (
    <InputNumber
      value={value}
      onChange={(v) => {
        setValue(v.target.value);
        onChangeValue("age", v.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

when I onChange in ChildInput1, then `ChildInput2` re-render, I don't want to the `ChildInput2` re-render. Example image

[image]

Comment: Here you are updating the `context` value and not internal state of the component, so re render happens in both of the child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey explained, you should fix the following line:

```
//you have
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue.InputNumber);
// should be
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue.age);
```

Additionally, `initValue` gets unnecessarily re-computed on every re-render, so it should be outside the scope of `Parent`:

```
const initValue = {
    name: "zhang",
    age: 3
  };

const Parent = () => {...}
```

Regarding re renderings, it is ok. When a Provider gets the value changed, all their childs wrapped in a consumer rerender. This is natural. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380624/react-context-when-are-children-re-rendered) explains why.

> A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context
> value changes. If re-rendering the component is expensive, you can
> optimize it by using memoization.

In this case, it is not expensive enough to consider memoization.

I Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```js
//you have
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue.InputNumber);
// should be
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue.age);
```

also update like that

```js
<InputNumber
  value={value}
  onChange={(value) => {
      setValue(value);
      onChangeValue("age", value);
  }}
/>
```

and when you fix like that do not worry about re-render as state of ChildInput2 will no be changed